# Adding onClick prop to children using cloneElement

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to create an image gallery component which displays small thumbnail images and a larger image 'preview'. The preview is replaced with the currently selected thumbnail.

The component allows any number of thumbnails to be passed in as children, and then an onClick prop is added to each thumbnail using cloneElement. This is working fine and I can see the new prop in the console, but nothing happens once the image is clicked. Here's my code so far:

**Parent**

```
<Gallery>
  {gallery.map((thumbnail) => {
    return (
      <Image fluid={thumbnail.asset.fluid} />
    );
  })}
</Gallery>
```

**Child**

```
const Gallery = (props) => {
    
  const [thumb, setThumb] = useState({
    preview: null,
  });

  const thumbnails = React.Children.map(props.children, (child) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, {
      onClick: () => {
        console.log("Clicked!")
        setThumb({
          preview: child.asset.fluid,
        });
      },
    })
  );
    
  return (
    <section>
      <div className={preview}>
        <Image fluid={preview} />
      </div>
      <div className={thumbnails}>
        {thumbnails}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

I'm not sure why I'm not getting any response (even in the console) when the thumbnails are clicked.

This is my first time using React so apologies if this is a terrible method, please let me know if there's a simpler/better way.

Comment: `Image` component will get it as `props.onClick`, it won't be automatically picked up as an event listeners, if you don't own `Image` you might want to wrap it around something that will add `onChick={props.onClick}`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Thank you so much, this solved the problem!

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by wrapping the `<Image>` component in a `<div>` as recommended by [Nadia Chibrikova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4434850/nadia-chibrikova):

**Parent**

```
<Gallery>
  {gallery.map((thumbnail) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Image fluid={thumbnail.asset.fluid} />
      </div>
    );
  })}
</Gallery>
```